# a better than naive implementation of strcspn()

Tags: c, algorithm

I have to figure out if my subject string has any of the bad characters(some characters i absolutely hate). so if i have a string called str`(char *str)` and if any of the characters in the string bad`(char *bad)` are found the string `str` is rejected. Now i could use `strcspn(str,bad)` to check this. But can somebody suggest what the implementation of `strcspn` could be?
A naive implementation would be to check each character of `str` against each character of `bad` and reject `str` if a match is found.

```
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
  for(j=0;bad[j]!='\0';j++)
    if(bad[j]==str[i])
       return -1;   //reject string
return 1;    //accept string
```

or something like

```
for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
  if(strchr(bad,str[i]))   //will return non-NULL if str[i] is found in bad
    return -1;   //reject string
return 1;    //accept string
```

Comment: Note that the condition in the inner for loop in the first snippet should be ``bad[j]!='\0'``, not ``bad[j]='\0'``.

Comment: @Tamás thanks. just missed the ! corrected it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `str` is very long (or you are going to check many strings against the same set of bad characters), you may gain some performance by creating a lookup table of size 256 where element *i* is 1 if the character with ASCII code *i* is bad and zero otherwise:

```
int contains_bad(const char* str, const char* bad) {
    unsigned short int table[256];
    char* ch;

    /* Prepare the lookup table */
    memset(table, 0, 256);
    for (ch = bad; *ch != 0; ch++)
        table[*ch] = 1;

    /* Test the string */
    for (ch = str; *ch != 0; ch++)
        if (table[*ch])
            return -1;

    return 1;
}
```

The above code is O(m+n) worst case, where *m* is the length of *bad* and *n* is the length of *str*; your solution is O(mn) worst case.

---

**Update**: here is the alternative version of the function which keeps the lookup table in static storage and clears it only once in every 255 invocations.

```
int contains_bad(const char* str, const char* bad) {
    static unsigned short int table[256];
    static unsigned short int marker = 255;
    char* ch;

    /* Prepare the lookup table */
    if (marker == 255) {
        memset(table, 0, 256);
        marker = 1;
    } else {
        marker++;
    }
    for (ch = bad; *ch != 0; ch++)
        table[*ch] = marker;

    /* Test the string */
    for (ch = str; *ch != 0; ch++)
         if (table[*ch] == marker)
             return -1;

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: thanks. when i was looking for the implementation of `strcspn` i stumbled upon [this link](http://sources.redhat.com/ml/libc-alpha/2005-06/msg00108.html) but cant make sense of it. Is the table driver approach the same thing what you are talking about

Comment: Yes, this is the usual table-driven approach. The implementation mentioned on that link uses an extra variable, say, `marker`, which is initially 1 and is increased by one after every invocation. The table is then filled with `marker` for bad characters, and also compared with `marker` in the second for loop. When `marker` reaches 256 (and overflows to zero), it is set to 1 and the table is cleared using `memset`. So, at the expense of some extra bookkeeping, you can asymptotically get rid of the cost of `memset`, but you have to make `table` and `marker` static or thread-local.

Comment: but why do you need `marker`? you can keep the table in static storage and set it once(non zero for bad characters).

Comment: Yes, but what if the function is called a second time with a different set of bad characters? Since `table` is now static, its contents persist between invocations, so you already have the bad characters of the previous invocation marked in the table, therefore you need a *different* marker to mark those that correspond to the current invocation.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about worst-case performance and/or thread safety, here's a variant that keeps the table on the stack.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int contains_bad(const char *str, const char *bad) {
  size_t hint[UCHAR_MAX];
  size_t len_bad;
  for (len_bad = 0; bad[len_bad]; len_bad++) {
    hint[(unsigned char)bad[len_bad] - 1] = len_bad;
  }
  for (; *str; str++) {
    size_t i = hint[(unsigned char)*str - 1];
    if (i < len_bad && *str == bad[i]) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(For the language lawyers: technically the uninitialized array `hint` can have trap representations lurking. If you know what this means and actually care about the behavior of C programs on long-dead platforms, one solution, if `bad` is a set and thus has no more than `UCHAR_MAX` characters, is to change `size_t hint[UCHAR_MAX]` to `unsigned char hint[UCHAR_MAX]`, since unsigned char is guaranteed not to have trap representations.)